# How to wait for angular-cli scripts loading to complete in Angular2

Tags: angular, materialize, angular-cli

I have an Angular2 App that uses Materialize-CSS via the scripts config directive of angular-cli package:

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js",
    "../node_modules/card/dist/card.js",
    "../node_modules/toastr/toastr.js"
  ],
```

The initial page of the App contains a carousel.

I am getting issues with the initialization of the carousel failing intermittently on initial App load, inside the materialize/jQuery javascript code.

The later I put the `.carousel()` call in the code, the less often it fails.

But even after doing:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout( () => { $('.carousel').carousel({full_width: 1}) }, 0);
}
```

it still fails sometimes. With a long timeout I can make it not fail at all but that feels very clumsy.

Is there any way I can make my component view depend on the scripts being fully initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I got your meaning: you want to trigger some function(out of the angular app) after the angular app finished initialization.

You can check [the post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3147-creating-an-event-driven-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-0-0.htm). The brief is, you can trigger some document event in angular app after some initialization, and listen this event and do the job you want.

Comment: No that was not my question. I am looking for a way to wait for all scripts loaded by the angular-cli `scripts` directive to be completely ready, before I start to call them, since obviously in my case they are getting called before they have completely loaded.